# Firebase - Importing Users using PBKDF2_SHA256 not working

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to import users from an old system into Firebase Auth. The old system uses PBKDF2 SHA256 to hash the passwords. I've written this example code, but it's not working:

```
  it("should import user correctly", async () => {
    const salt = crypto.randomBytes(16);
    const rounds = 10000;
    const passwordStr = "Test123();";
    const email = "test123@test.com";

    const password = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(Buffer.from(passwordStr, "utf-8"), salt, rounds, 32, "sha256");
    const importResult = await getAuth().importUsers(
      [{ email, passwordHash: password, passwordSalt: salt, uid: "123456" }],
      {
        hash: { algorithm: "PBKDF2_SHA256", rounds },
      },
    );
    expect(importResult.successCount).toBe(1);

    const body = { email, password: passwordStr };
    const response = await fetch(
      "http://localhost:9099/identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key=asdf",
      {
        method: "post",
        body: JSON.stringify(body),
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      },
    );
    expect(response.status).toBe(200);
  });
```

Am I missing something? The import is successful, but the signIn request returns

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 400,
        "message": "INVALID_PASSWORD",
        "errors": [
            {
                "message": "INVALID_PASSWORD",
                "reason": "invalid",
                "domain": "global"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out to be a problem with the firebase emulator. Using a real firebase project everything works fine